# Qual a diferença entre os operadores <@> e <->

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocalização

Estava estudando tipos geométricos e coordenadas em SQL, no PostgreSQL mais especificamente, e me deparei com dois operadores, o operador **<@>** e o operador **<->**. Qual a diferença entre eles? Qual é o mais rápido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O operador `<->` (distância entre 2 objetos), definido no próprio PostgreSQL, é utilizado com objetos de um espaço bidimensional.

O operador `<@>` (point <@> point), definido no módulo extra "earthdistance", é utilizado para o cálculo de distâncias na superfície da terra e leva em conta a latitude e longitude dos pontos.

Comment: A distancia da superfície da terra não  pode ser considerada um espaço bidimensional a final de contas usamos X e Y (lat lng)? Pelo que eu vi o <-> funciona com Point também, então qual dois métodos seria o mais rapido?

Comment: Segundo os terraplanistas, sim.

Comment: É que no caso do Point não estamos considerando a altitude, apenas a latitude e longitude, então e se colocarmos a terra em um plano reto ela se torna um espaço bidimensional, ou a latitude e longitude não podem ser considerados como X e Y ?

Comment: O módulo "earthdistance" leva em conta a curvatura da superfície da terra. Lembre-se apenas que é uma aproximação (considera a Terra como uma esfera perfeita), caso necessite de maior exatidão avalie a utilização do PostGIS.

Comment: No meu caso eu preciso mais de otimização do que de precisão, a precisão pra mim não é importante, fiz alguns benchmarks comparando tanto o  PostGIS quanto outros e acabei não sendo muito feliz nos resultados, então em busca de soluções mais ágeis acabei encontrando os operadores de distancia, porém não encontrei muitas explicações que dissessem com exatidão a diferença entre eles, tudo que a documentação dizia é que eles retornavam a distancia entre 2 pontos, mas agora faz mais sentido. O que eu preciso é só ordenar pelos mais próximos então eu também não me importo com a unidade de medida.